# Add attachment to bug by url

Tags: c#, api, fogbugz

I tried with this url:

```
https://myPath.fogbugz.com/api.asp?cmd=new&sTitle=sometitle&ixProject=1&token=12345678910111213&FileName=C:\Users\John\Desktop\xxx.txt
```

and the issue is created, but the attachment no. How to do this?

Comment: Which HTTP method are you using? GET, POST, PUT?

Comment: I don't know their API at all but if you want to transfer a file to a web site, PUT or POST are usually the methods for doing so. I would guess they're expecting a PUT.

Comment: @M.Babcock But the bug is created!

Comment: I understand that, but you never sent them the file to attach to the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use POST rather than GET, POSTing in `multipart/form-data` format and passing in the files as type "file" and name "File1", "File2", "File3" etc, with a "nFileCount" parameter set to the total number of files being sent.

Have a look at the [Editing Cases](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/fogbugz-xml-api#editingcases) section in the XML API docs for further details.